# How to use custom SQL function in dbplyr?

Tags: r, stringdist, dbplyr

I would like to calculate the Jaro-Winkler string distance in a database. If I bring the data into R (with `collect`) I can easily use the `stringdist` function from the `stringdist` package.

But my data is very large and I'd like to filter on Jaro-Winkler distances *before* pulling the data into R.

There is SQL code for Jaro-Winkler (https://androidaddicted.wordpress.com/2010/06/01/jaro-winkler-sql-code/ and a version for [T-SQL](https://gist.github.com/paulirwin/dcfa49700fb7b290705007ca37d66494)) but I guess I'm not sure how best to get that SQL code to work with `dbplyr`. I'm happy to try and map the `stringdist` function to the Jaro-Winkler `sql` code but I don't know where to start on that. But even something simpler like executing the SQL code directly from R on the remote data would be great.

I had hoped that [SQL translation](http://dbplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/sql-translation.html) in the `dbplyr` documentation might help, but I don't think so.

Comment: Could you please provide a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example with the sample data code baked into it? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Can you just make a SQL call directly and use dplyr after you being your data in?

Answer (score 6):

You can build your own SQL functions in R. They just have to produce a string that is a valid SQL query. I don't know the Jaro-Winkler distance, but I can provide an example for you to build from:

```
union_all = function(table_a,table_b, list_of_columns){
  # extract database connection
  connection = table_a$src$con

  sql_query = build_sql(con = connection,
                      sql_render(table_a),
                      "\nUNION ALL\n",
                      sql_render(table_b)
  )

  return(tbl(connection, sql(sql_query)))
}

unioned_table = union_all(table_1, table_2, c("who", "where", "when"))
```

Two key commands here are:

- `sql_render`, which takes a dbplyr table and returns the SQL code that produces it
- `build_sql`, which assembles a query from strings.

You have choices for your execution command:

- `tbl(connection, sql(sql_query))` will return the resulting table
- `dbExecute(db_connection, as.character(sql_query))` will execute a query without returning the result (useful for for dropping tables, creating indexes, etc.)

Comment: I have tried out your solution and it works. But I am bothered with one thing: the first time dbplyr connects to a database via `table_a <-tbl(con, "table_a")`  it needs to do a dummy query, i.e. "select * from table_a where 0 = 1". If I now use R object table_a  in the sql_render/build_sql, it will do the same type of WHERE 0 = 1  query again. Is there a way to prevent dbplyr to do that and instead reuse the meta-data from the first tbl(...) call?

Comment: I have seen dbplyr produce SQL queries containing `WHERE 0 = 1` but they have never effected my custom SQL functions. It might be due to how you connect to the SQL tables, or because you call `render_sql(tbl(con, "table_a"))` instead of first assigning `tbl_a = tbl(con, "table_a")` before calling `render_sql(tbl_a)`. But I can not tell from the details you have provided. Consider opening a new question and posting a link to it here - I can take a more detailed look.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, find a way to define the function in SQL as a user-defined function, you can then simply use the name of that function as if it were an R function (in a dbplyr query).  When R can't find the function locally, it simply passes it to the SQL back-end and assumes it will be a function thats available in SQL-land.

This is a great way to decouple the logic.  Down side is that the dbplyr expression is now dependant on the db-backend; you can't run the came code on a local data set.  One way around *that* is to create a UDF that mimics an existing R function.  The `dplyr` will use the local R and `dbplyr` will use the SQL UDF.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sql()` which runs whatever raw SQL you provide.

#### Example

Here the lubridate equivalent doesn't work on a database backend.

So instead I place custom SQL code `sql("EXTRACT(WEEK FROM ildate)")` inside `sql()`, like so:

```r
your_dbplyr_object %>%
  mutate(week = sql("EXTRACT(WEEK FROM meeting_date)"))
```

---

One other thing, this is the top search result when searching for how to render the raw sql using dbplyr. In case anyone arrived here from that search, the answer is to pipe to `dbplyr::sql_render()`. From the docs:

> `sql_build()` creates a select_query S3 object, that is rendered to a SQL string by `sql_render()`