# Using dbplyr starting from a given SQL query in dbplyr

Tags: sql, r, dplyr, dbplyr

I have a rather long and convoluted query that I use as a starting point for doing some analysis. I have replicated that one from scratch using dbplyr so I can use dplyr verbs without getting the database into memory. How can I achieve this without having to replicate the starting query using dbplyr?

Comment: Are you asking for a way to automatically translate SQL into dplyr (so dbplyr can then translate it back into SQL)? An example would assist.

Comment: This post gives the SQL to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75524437/emulating-sliders-slide-index-functions-in-sql-for-non-consecutively/75524892#75524892

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52394311/7742981) answer. It explicitly sets the SQL query for a dbplyr table. You can use the same idea:

```r
# read file containing existing query
start_query = your_favorite_way_to_read_file_here(file_name)

# create connection
con = DBI::dbConnect(...)

# initial table
my_table = tbl(con, sql(start_query))
```

To verify that it has worked as intended try `show_query(my_table)` or `head(my_table)`.

Note that dbplyr does not translate dplyr into highly optimized queries. So if your initial query is complex / slow to run, adding further manipulation via dbplyr could perform poorly. In this case it might be better to write your complex query to another table.

Comment: "Adding further manipulation via `dbplyr` could perform poorly." Indeed! One way to " write your complex query to another table" would be simply to append `%>% compute()` to the end of the line creating `my_table`.