# Emulating `slider`'s `slide_index_*()` functions in `SQL` for Non-Consecutively-Ordered Sliding Window Frames

Tags: sql, r, dplyr, window-functions

Consider the following table:

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

apple_tbl <-
    tribble(
        ~ "VENDOR", ~ "WEEK_IN_YEAR", ~ "APPLES_SOLD" 
        , "A", 10, 20
        , "A", 15, 10
        , "A", 17, 5
        , "B", 11, 25
        , "B", 12, 18
        , "B", 18, 30
        , "C", 10, 5
    )

apple_tbl
#> # A tibble: 7 × 3
#>   VENDOR WEEK_IN_YEAR APPLES_SOLD
#>   <chr>         <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1 A                10          20
#> 2 A                15          10
#> 3 A                17           5
#> 4 B                11          25
#> 5 B                12          18
#> 6 B                18          30
#> 7 C                10           5
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Notice how the weeks for each vendor, while ordered, are not in *consecutive* order; for Vendor `A`, we do not have weeks *11* through *14*, nor *16*, for example.

So trying to do a sum of the past-4-weeks'-worth of apples sold by each vendor is not really possible in `SQL`, as far as I know, but `slider` makes this very easy to calculate:

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = F)
library(slider)

apple_tbl <-
    tribble(
        ~ "VENDOR", ~ "WEEK_IN_YEAR", ~ "APPLES_SOLD" 
        , "A", 10, 20
        , "A", 15, 10
        , "A", 17, 5
        , "B", 11, 25
        , "B", 12, 18
        , "B", 18, 30
        , "C", 10, 5
    )

apple_tbl %>%
    group_by(VENDOR) %>%
    mutate(
        APPLES_SOLD_PAST_4_WEEKS = 
            slide_index_sum(
                x = APPLES_SOLD # The vector being calculated/summed
                , i = WEEK_IN_YEAR # The vector that is being referenced/tracked by `slider`
                , before = 4 # From 4 weeks prior
                , after = 0 # To the current row's week
            )
    ) %>%
    ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 7 × 4
#>   VENDOR WEEK_IN_YEAR APPLES_SOLD APPLES_SOLD_PAST_4_WEEKS
#>   <chr>         <dbl>       <dbl>                    <dbl>
#> 1 A                10          20                       20
#> 2 A                15          10                       10
#> 3 A                17           5                       15
#> 4 B                11          25                       25
#> 5 B                12          18                       43
#> 6 B                18          30                       30
#> 7 C                10           5                        5
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

As `slider`, over an alternative like `RcppRoll`, can handle missing values in the "index" column (`WEEK_IN_YEAR` for this example).

The closest I can think of (using *Snowflake* as my reference point) would be this query:

```sql
SELECT
   VENDOR
   , WEEK_IN_YEAR
   , APPLES_SOLD
   , SUM(APPLES_SOLD) OVER (PARTITION BY VENDOR ORDER BY WEEK_IN_YEAR ASC ROWS BETWEEN 4 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) APPLES_SOLD_PAST_4_ROWS -- Not the same thing
FROM apple_tbl
```

[image]

But this falls apart immediately as the "reference" column (`WEEK_IN_YEAR` in this case) is not in *consecutive* order for each vendor.

The only other thing I can really think of is to have some sort of `DIM_DATE` table containing all weeks in the year, and doing a cross/left-join of the main `FCT` apple-sales-history table, and fill the missing weeks in (with a `0` for example). However, **at scale** this seems inelegant, or wasteful in terms of compute/time.

Any suggestion on how to do this in plain `SQL` would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a self-join on the condition:

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select a.*, sum(b.APPLES_SOLD) as APPLES_SOLD_PAST_4_WEEKS
  from apple_tbl a
  left join apple_tbl b
    on b.WEEK_IN_YEAR between a.WEEK_IN_YEAR - 4 and a.WEEK_IN_YEAR
      and a.VENDOR = b.VENDOR
  group by a.rowid
  order by a.rowid")
```

giving:

```
  VENDOR WEEK_IN_YEAR APPLES_SOLD APPLES_SOLD_PAST_4_WEEKS
1      A           10          20                       20
2      A           15          10                       10
3      A           17           5                       15
4      B           11          25                       25
5      B           12          18                       43
6      B           18          30                       30
7      C           10           5                        5
```

Note that `rollapplyr` in zoo can also handle this.  See the examples section on the help page.

Comment: That's pretty slick. I guess technically it's a single-table solution, which is what I was looking for. Didn't think of a `JOIN` using `BETWEEN` either. Thanks.